# Selecting message language in gcc and g++

Tags: gcc, localization, g++

I use `gcc`/`g++` on Linux and since my install is in Spanish (my native language), `gcc` prints warnings and errors in Spanish. I would rather read them in English for two reasons:

1. English messages are far easier to google.
2. Spanish translations are more or less horrible.

Any help?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try to change the `LANG` environment variable: [http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.0/gcc/Environment-Variables.html#Environment-Variables](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.0/gcc/Environment-Variables.html#Environment-Variables/).

Comment: For me it was the `LANGUAGE` environment variable

Answer (score 20):

The end of the GCC manpage contains an overview of its locale environment variables:

> - LANG
> - LC_CTYPE
> - LC_MESSAGES
> - LC_ALL
>
> These environment variables control the way that GCC uses localization information that allow GCC to work with different national conventions.  GCC inspects the locale categories `LC_CTYPE` and `LC_MESSAGES` if it has been configured to do so. These locale categories can be set to any value supported by your installation.  A typical value is en_GB.UTF-8 for English in the United Kingdom encoded in UTF-8.
>
> The `LC_CTYPE` environment variable specifies character classification.  GCC uses it to determine the character boundaries in a string; this is needed for some multibyte encodings that contain quote and escape characters that would otherwise be interpreted as a string end or escape.
>
> The `LC_MESSAGES` environment variable specifies the language to use in diagnostic messages.
>
> If the `LC_ALL` environment variable is set, it overrides the value of LC_CTYPE and `LC_MESSAGES`; otherwise, `LC_CTYPE` and `LC_MESSAGES` default to the value of the LANG environment variable.  If none of these variables are set, GCC defaults to traditional C English behavior.

I do this:

```
LC_MESSAGES=C gcc-command-here
```

Comment: Weird LC_MESSAGES=C had no effect on the error being reported in UTF-8 while LC_ALL=C definitely did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

To change the gcc translations to English, to must set the environment variable LANG to English:

$ export LANG=en

add it to your .profile file and it will always be in English

Comment: Or less intrusively `LANG=en <CMD> [ARGS...]` when working directly in the shell.

Comment: To make sure it works with all programs, the locale should include an encoding, and it must be a generated locale - one of the list in `locale -a`. For example, `en_US.UTF-8` is often a good choice, but there's no guarantee even that is generated (see raspberry pi)