# gcc ignores LC_ALL

Tags: gcc, localization, ubuntu

I was trying to get gcc give error message in a different language. But it still gives me the error message in english.

my locale output
varun@varun-desktop:$ locale
LANG=en_IN

LC_CTYPE="es_EC.utf8"

LC_NUMERIC="es_EC.utf8"

LC_TIME="es_EC.utf8"

LC_COLLATE="es_EC.utf8"

LC_MONETARY="es_EC.utf8"

LC_MESSAGES="es_EC.utf8"

LC_PAPER="es_EC.utf8"

LC_NAME="es_EC.utf8"

LC_ADDRESS="es_EC.utf8"

LC_TELEPHONE="es_EC.utf8"

LC_MEASUREMENT="es_EC.utf8"

LC_IDENTIFICATION="es_EC.utf8"

LC_ALL=es_EC.utf8

gcc.mo is present in my /usr/share/local/es

i am also getting the error messages for other programs like apt in spanish but not gcc.
Can anybody help me in this regard??

I am using gcc-4.4.3 on 64bit ubuntu 10.04 machine

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting `LANG`: see [Selecting message language in gcc and g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869309) for a detailed description of related environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know gcc isn't localized, so you can only get English error messages.