# erase function in a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to learn c++. This code compile just fine without the delSong function. But with it, it won't compile. And I can't figure out what I have been doing wrong... :-/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Jukebox {

public:
  void addSong(string artist, string title, string filename) {
    songCounter++;
    song s {songCounter, artist, title, filename};
    Songs.push_back(s);
  }

  void delSong(int pos) {
    Songs.erase(pos);
  }

  void printSong(int pos) {
    cout << Songs[pos].no << ". ";
    cout << Songs[pos].artist << " - ";
    cout << Songs[pos].title << " : ";
    cout << Songs[pos].filename << endl;
  }

  void printSongs() {
    for (int i = 0; i < Songs.size(); i++) {
      printSong(i);
    }
  }

  Jukebox(): songCounter(0) {}

private:
  int songCounter;
  struct song {
    int no;
    string artist;
    string title;
    string filename;
  };
  vector<song> Songs;
};

int main() {
  Jukebox jbox;
  jbox.addSong("U2", "Magnificent", "U2-Magnificent.mp3");
  jbox.addSong("Sting", "Englishman in New York", "Sting-Englishman_in_New_York.mp3");
  jbox.addSong("U2", "One", "U2-One.mp3");
  jbox.printSongs();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Give us compiler error that you get.

Comment: Sorry. It won't compile. I could edit the question to fix it. But one my other newbie problems are that g++ output error messages in swedish. So I have to find some locale-setting if I should show the error message.

Comment: Hey I want to learn Swedish! :D BTW you could try to compile on `ideone.com`, it has an locale there.

Comment: Oh, ideone.com - that was cool. Have to play with it a bit! :-) I could probably customize emacs to change locale before compiling. I will look in to it so I don't need to get downvoted for not bringing the error message :-)

Comment: @Niclas - Swedish is not a problem! :-)

Comment: @Niclas - And if it is a problem, Stackoverflow has a solution to that: [Selecting message language in gcc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869309/selecting-message-language-in-gcc-and-g)

Comment: @BoPersson Yeah! I just figured that out. Now I just want emacs to always change the LANG for me just for `make`... But that's a whole other question. Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: @NiclasNilsson: this is not directly related to your question, however: in C++ it is better to pass string class instances input arguments by const reference instead of by value (it is more efficient, and avoids a copy constructor call), so you may want to update your method like this: "void addSong(const string & artist, const string & title, const string & filename)".

Comment: @Mr_C64: ok. I look into it. The whole point of this code is for me to learn. So very thankful for the input!

Comment: @Mr_C64 I've tried to read to understand the difference of your code snippet and mine. Declaring them as `const` really make sense to me now. But I don't understand why i should add the `&`? From what I understand they make it possible for the function to modify the external variable passed to it. But that function would not need that. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @NiclasNilsson: Passing by reference (&) is like passing by pointer (in semantics), but the syntax is that of passing by value. As you already read, if you pass by reference - because you are actually passing a pointer - the pointed variable can be modified. Considering that in your case the parameters are input parameters (i.e. read-only), I suggested using the 'const' specifier, so: passing by const reference (const std::string &). Passing by const reference doesn't allow modification of the variable ('const'), and at the same time is efficient as passing by pointer (reference/'&').

Comment: Doh. Of course! That makes total sense now! :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look how `erase` is defined:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/erase/

```
iterator erase ( iterator position );
iterator erase ( iterator first, iterator last );
```

It takes iterators, not indices, as arguments. So instead of

```
Songs.erase(5);
```

try:

```
Songs.erase(Songs.begin() + 5);
```

`begin()` returns an iterator and `+5` moves it to the position which is to be deleted.

Comment: +1 for reference. All people new to a programming language need to know where to look stuff up.

Answer (score 2):

The `std::vector<T>::erase()` function doesn't take an index. It takes an iterator. If you want to get an iterator from an index with a random access container (like e.g. `std::vector<T>`) you can just use `begin()` and add the corresponding offset:

```
this->Songs.erase(this->Songs.begin() + pos);
```